# How to measure http(s) requests sent per second sent by my executable?

Tags: c++, http, curl, requests-per-second

I have a C++ executable which makes use of cURL to make HTTP(s) requests to an external server. Is there a good way for me to determine the requests sent per second? Any way or tool will be helpful.

Comment: Is it merely an executable or your compiled code?

Comment: @wquinoa : I have the code with me .. but would be interested to know any external tool as well for measuring this by adding any additional code.

Answer (score 1):

Increment a counter every time the application makes a request. Have a separate timer that checks and resets the counter every second. Average the values over time as needed.

Comment: Is there any external tool for sniffing this as i don't want to add additional processing code which can cause latency.